# SQL using alias in new calculation

Tags: sql

I want to show another column as per the image.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcj8m.png)

My current code:

```
SELECT 
activity_name,
budgeted_labor_units/
(SELECT
    SUM(budgeted_labor_units) AS total_manhours_str
FROM 
    `durable-torus-319013.testing_pms.pms_table`
WHERE 
    l8 IS NOT NULL) AS weightage_per_activity,
(SELECT weightage_per_activity) * 100 AS test_column
FROM 
    `durable-torus-319013.testing_pms.pms_table`
WHERE 
    l8 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY budgeted_labor_units DESC 

LIMIT 5
```

When I run the query, I have this error:

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword SELECT at [10:5]

I know that I could just multiply the alias * 100 but I have another calculation that requires using the alias as a new calculation and also has to show in the table.

TIA

Comment: please add you specific database, table structure and what do you mean in query where it says `18 is not null`

Comment: I think that's an identifier (ell 8), not 1 8.

Comment: In some databases (like MySQL or Maria) something like this ```SELECT expression AS xname, (SELECT xname + 1) AS c2, ...``` is a way to use derived column names within the same select list.  The FROM clause isn't required, even though standard SQL requires it.

Comment: Yup got it @JonArmstrong . I thought it was table column but later on found about derived column that's why deleted .

Comment: I wonder if ```durable-torus-319013.testing_pms.pms_table``` is not meant to be quoted as one identifier. I prefer to avoid quoting unless necessary to avoid these messes.

Comment: The above SQL is valid in MariaDB and MySQL.  I tested it locally.  But I also created that strange table with the name given above.  I'm not sure that's correct in the real schema.  That detail would be nice to know.

Comment: sorry. im quite new. just finish the google data analyst cert. im using big query for starter. 

the "l8 IS NOT NULL" is a column with header titled "L8" or "l8".

Comment: all the code is copied directly from google big query . the 'durable-torus-319013.testing_pms.pms_table' is the table directory name. since im using trial version @JonArmstrong . sorry this is my first post at stackoverflow

Comment: No problem.  I created a test bigquery environment.  bigquery doesn't support the ```(SELECT colname)``` form.  I'll add an answer below with a form of SQL that bigquery does support.  Note: The table name had to be changed due to some default scope and pre-existing schema / objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a form of the SQL that bigquery does support.  Adjust the project based table name as needed for your environment:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
      SELECT t.*
           , budgeted_labor_units /
               (SELECT SUM(budgeted_labor_units) AS total_manhours_str
                  FROM `project-01-321411.my_pms_table.my_pms_table`
                 WHERE l8 IS NOT NULL
               ) AS weightage_per_activity
        FROM `project-01-321411.my_pms_table.my_pms_table` AS t
       WHERE l8 IS NOT NULL
     )
SELECT activity_name
     , weightage_per_activity
     , weightage_per_activity * 100 AS test_column
  FROM cte1
 ORDER BY budgeted_labor_units DESC 
 LIMIT 5
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions and repeat the expression:

```
SELECT activity_name,
       (budgeted_labor_units / SUM(budgeted_labor_units) OVER ()) as weightage_per_activity,
       (100 * budgeted_labor_units / SUM(budgeted_labor_units) OVER ()) as test_column
FROM `durable-torus-319013.testing_pms.pms_table`
WHERE l8 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY budgeted_labor_units DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

You can also use a CTE or subquery for more complicated expressions.  But in this case, getting rid of the subquery is the best approach.